# Cominatorial Geometry

Tags: combinatorics

Where on the internet can I find free information in etutorial or ebook form
on Discrete Geometry (Combinatorial Geometry) (diagrams and pictures are always
nice).I've given google 20 minutes of searching but only found some wikipedia articles. I'm currently not enrolled in school but am a programmer by trade.
Also, What are the prerequisites for Combinatorial Geometry?

Thank you!
John

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

H. Hadwiger, H. Debrunner, Combinatorial Geometry in the Plane

or

A. Szilárd, Elementary combinatorial geometry?

Comment: sorry I didn't mean either. I asked a question concerning free Combinatorial Geometry books.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know English well, so I didn't understand your question. Do you find free e-books on Combinatorial Geometry?  I have mentioned books as  e-books.

Comment: thats ok. google seems to be protecting the interest of doctors by not allowing us Earthlings easy access to written math knowledge. sorry.

Comment: If you write e-mail to me, I will send you the books.

Comment: Well, thank you. But if it's not legal I wouldn't want to take away the money from the Doctors involved. Isn't there anything free online I can download? Why isn't this public information? Is it considered dangerous?

Comment: I think I have the right to give you a thing which I possess.